# Complex Analysis Exercise (J.B.Conway)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have currently started solving the exercises from the book Functions of one complex variable by J.B. Conway.This is a problem from the exercise of Chapter 1.It looks very simple and I can imagine it very well but having problem to get an analytical solution.

[image]

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: What do S and N stand for ? Is it the Riemann sphere its north pole ?

Comment: Hint: intersection of the planes is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Astyx ,S is the unit sphere and N is its north pole.....

Comment: Yes I can imagine that but need some analytical proof.....

Comment: The dimension of a plane in $\Bbb R^3$ is 2, thus the dimension of the intersection of 2 planes is at most 2. If it was 2, you would have $\Bbb C = P$ which is obviously not true since $S \cap \Bbb C = \{0\}$. Therefore the intersection is a line.

Comment: Its the stereographic projection the projection that is told in the question.....It also mentions,"Otherwise it projects onto a circle".